# Set cookie for root page only

Tags: php, cookies

There seems to be very little info covering this. The site's homepage is simply '/' as opposed to '/index.php'. When using:

```
setcookie('values[value]', $_POST['value'], time()+99999, '/' );
```

The above line will overwrite all cookies for every path on the domain. However I want this cookie to be set for the *homepage only*. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: You cannot. / (root path) will set cookie that will available on all subdirectories

Comment: Is there any work around to achieve the same thing? May have to look at redirecting the homepage to a subfolder... Doesn't seem practical.

Comment: Well, you can check cookie in your script to determine what's exactly url is

Comment: We can't really suggest alternatives to achieve the same thing because we don't know your ultimate goal. I've found `LocalStorage` pretty convenient for almost everything I was previously doing with cookies but, as I said, it depends on what you want the cookie for.

Comment: Think I may rip out all my php cookies and switch to local storage. This root issue is basically catastrophic for the code I have. Thanks for the pointer Alvaro, will research it.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible. The path section for [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.4) says:

> A request-path path-matches a given cookie-path if at least one of
> the following conditions holds:
>
> - The cookie-path and the request-path are identical.
> - The
>   cookie-path is a prefix of the request-path, and the last
>   character of the cookie-path is %x2F ("/").
> - The cookie-path is a prefix of the request-path, and the first
>   character of the request-path that is not included in the cookie-
>   path is a %x2F ("/") character.

That provides no provision to match `/` without matching `/foo`.